# Web.config - Target database from parent-folder

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config

I've a database is in `App_Data` folder within my application folder. I would like to move the database to the root/parent folder (in parent-folder to my application) and still be able to access it.

```
-(root)The_database_where_I_want_to_use.db
- - ApplicationFolder
- - - App_Data/MyDatabase.db
```

This is my current connectionstring in **Web.config**:

```
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
     Data Source = |DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

How can I target "`The_database_where_I_want_to_use.db`" in root folder ?

Comment: Have you tried leaving only `Data Source = The_database_where_I_want_to_use.mdb`?

Answer (score 0):

you can configure `Data Source = ./MyDatabase.mdb"'

the dot  is the root of the web application

```
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
 Data Source = ./MyDatabase.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```